# Does Signature PAD by Thomas Bradley work in Android via Phonegap

Tags: android, canvas, cordova

I need to capture a signature on a Canvas Element on a touch Android Device (Droid X)

Does Signature PAD  by Thomas Bradley work in Native Android via Phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

it should work, the challenge would be loading in all of jquery, and you might run into some performance issues.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It *should* work, PhoneGap does support the touch events.